# SQL statement to SUM values in one column by distinct values in another column while grouping by a third column?

Tags: sql, netsuite, suiteql

I am trying to write a SQL statement to report the total amount an agent has sold and a count of the products they have sold from another table. I'm having difficulty getting the SUM data to come out right. There is a parent File record that has several child product records to it.

Sample schema:

transaction_file

| ID | AGENT | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 40 |
| 2 | B | 38 |
| 3 | A | 40 |

transaction_product

| ID | PARENT_FILE |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 14 | 3 |
| 15 | 2 |
| 16 | 2 |

Joining the tables comes out as

| FILE_ID | AGENT | AMT | PRODUCT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 40 | 11 |
| 1 | A | 40 | 12 |
| 3 | A | 40 | 13 |
| 3 | A | 40 | 14 |
| 2 | B | 38 | 15 |
| 2 | B | 38 | 16 |

Desired Results

| AGENT | SUM AMT | PRODUCT COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 80 | 4 |
| B | 38 | 2 |

I need to group by the Agent show the product count then sum the AMT by the distinct FILE_ID.

I've tried my SQL state a couple of ways and can't get the sum of the AMT to come out right. My current SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    File.agent,
    COUNT(Product.id) product_count,
    SUM(DISTINCT File.amt) sum_amt

FROM transaction_file File

INNER JOIN transaction_product Product ON Product.parent_file = File.id

WHERE File.id IN (1, 2, 3)

GROUP BY File.agent
```

Produces:

| AGENT | SUM AMT | PRODUCT COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 40 | 4 |
| B | 38 | 2 |

AND

```
SELECT
    File.agent,
    COUNT(Product.id) product_count,
    SUM(File.amt) sum_amt

FROM transaction_file File

INNER JOIN transaction_product Product ON Product.parent_file = File.id

WHERE File.id IN (1, 2, 3)

GROUP BY File.agent
```

Produces:

| AGENT | SUM AMT | PRODUCT COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 120 | 4 |
| B | 76 | 2 |

I've tried a couple of subqueries, but I can't get those to work at all.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a `CTE` to build the required sum per agent and then `JOIN` the result to your main query.

This will be the query that selects the sum per agent:

```
SELECT 
  agent, 
  SUM(amt) AS sum_amt
FROM transaction_file
GROUP BY agent;
```

So the entire query will be this one:

```
WITH Sums AS 
  (SELECT 
     agent, 
     SUM(amt) AS sum_amt
   FROM transaction_file
   GROUP BY agent)
SELECT
  f.agent,
  s.sum_amt,
  COUNT(p.id) AS product_count
FROM 
  transaction_file f
  INNER JOIN transaction_product p 
    ON p.parent_file = f.id
  INNER JOIN sums s
    ON f.agent = s.agent
WHERE 
  f.id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY 
  f.agent, 
  s.sum_amt;
```

This will be the result of the query for your sample data:

| AGENT | SUM AMT | PRODUCT COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 80 | 4 |
| B | 38 | 2 |

See this [fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/opWXup4b)

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. So the CTE is like a block of results to an individual set of queries on?

Comment: @Jonas Metzler, thank you for this answer. Why is the 'WHERE f.id IN (1, 2, 3)' condition needed?

Comment: @PreethamSolomon That condition was named by OP in their question, so I assumed they need it.

Comment: @MatthewCarter CTE means Common Table Expression, that's something like a temporary result of a query which makes it easier than using complicated subqueries. You can select from this result set or execute DELETE/UPDATE on it as you would directly change the original table.